# How to check if a Team drive is Trashed in Google Drive REST API?

Tags: php, python, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

Is their a way to check by making an API call to google Drive that if a particular Team Drive is Trashed or not?

I have tried to do a GET request to the particular Team drive which is trashed by the user. But I get 200 response, So how can I detect the team-drive was trashed by user

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/teamdrives/{trashed-team-drive-id}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the [Changes: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list), you can check here your most recent file/folder changes. Including the changes for folder movements as well as trashed files.

Here are the steps that you need to do:

- Use [Changes: getStartPageToken](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/getStartPageToken) and pass the value **true** to the `supportsTeamDrives` parameter. Just get the value that you will get from it because you will use it in the next step. eg. **"startPageToken": "1203685"**
- You can now use the Changes: list to get the changes in your teamDrive. Here are the parameter that you need to pass:

  - `pagetoken` - 1203685 // the value that you get in the above step.
  - `includeRemoved` - true
  - `includeTeamDriveItems` - true
  - `supportsTeamDrives` - true
  - `teamDriveId` - YOUR_TEAM_DRIVE_ID

After you execute this step, you will receive something like this:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#changeList",
 "newStartPageToken": "25",
 "changes": []
}
```

- Now, you need to use this **25** as your pagetoken, again you will receive the same results, because you are using the most recent page token. You need to manually reduce the page token until you received the changes.

Here are the sample parameter and sample results.

- `pagetoken` - 25 // then use 24, to check the latest changes, then 23 and so on.
- `includeRemoved` - true
- `includeTeamDriveItems` - true
- `supportsTeamDrives` - true
- `teamDriveId` - YOUR_TEAM_DRIVE_ID

Sample results

```
{
 "kind": "drive#changeList",
 "newStartPageToken": "25",
 "changes": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#change",
   "type": "file",
   "time": "2017-03-23T09:23:43.399Z",
   "removed": true,
   "fileId": "1JByPgn1GVybkprMC0NX_t0o6xxxxD6ZnuVqo1Kymjqk"
  }
 ]
}
```

For more information, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-teamdrives) about Team Drive.

## Updated Answer

Well, the only way that I can see to determine if the Team Drive is deleted or not is by checking if it is available in the [`Teamdrives: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/list)

You will see here all the available team drive that you have.

In my case I have three team drive so the result is like this:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#teamDriveList",
 "teamDrives": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0AMlDYsxxxxLYUk9PVA"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0ABe6rxxxxzGaUk9PVA"
  },

  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0ABgqxxxxgt-NUk9PVA"
  }
```

You can also verify it if you know the id of the team drive by using the [`Teamdrives: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/teamdrives/get)

I tried to delete one of the team drive **"0AMlDYsxxxxLYUk9PV"** and perform again the
Teamdrives: list. Now, I only get the two results

```
{
 "kind": "drive#teamDriveList",
 "teamDrives": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0ABe6rxxxxzGaUk9PVA"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#teamDrive",
   "id": "0ABgqxxxxgt-NUk9PVA"
  }
```

And if I use now the Teamdrives: get for the teamDriveId **"0AMlDYsxxxxLYUk9PV"**, I will now receive an **error 404: "Team Drive not found: 0AMlDYsxxxxLYUk9PV"**

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I am looking for a solution to know whether the team-drive is deleted or not. I have get the all the changes by **Changes.list** But I didn't find any item to indicate the team-drive is deleted

Comment: Did you mean the whole team drive? Or the file inside the team drive?

Comment: whole team-drive, not a single file inside the team-drive.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi , It was working as per need. Thanks once again for saving my time